# error messages upon installation of new ubuntu 14

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, error-handling

1)  I have a link to ubuntu (for previous version) on the boot menu.  However when I click on that link I get a black screen (no writing). My guess is that ubuntu crashed and disappeared, since I can not find it when I boot to Windows 8.1.

2a) With the DVD in the correct drive I shut down computer with Windows 8.1

2b) I start with choosing CD/DVD drive

2c) A black screen with lots of error message with consecutive numbers appear.

I don't seemed to be able to get rid of that.  I had no problems with a previous version of uBuntu, which as mentioned has disappeared.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Gabriele